# Newly created elements without jquery expando attribute aren't maintained by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have collapsable/expandable [tree](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview) created in jQuery.
After loading the tree:

```
$("#tree").treeview({
        collapsed: true,
        animated: "medium",
        control: "#sidetreecontrol",
        persist: "location"
    });
```

I have expando data attribute on the nodes, for example:

[image]

I've written some code which appends new nodes to my existing ones, basically by creating new `<ul><li>` html elements. So after appending a new node, I have additional ul container, but without **jQueryxxxxx...** attribute:

[image]

While I'm able to expand and collapse nodes initialized on page loading, I'm not able to interact with the nodes I've added later, because they're not cached... ? I don't understand that and I don't know how to fix it to be able to collapse and expand nodes I've created after the tree is initialized.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default *no* elements have the jQuery expando attribute, it's added when events or data are added to the element.  This is something your `.treeview()` plugin is doing, e.g. adding `click` handlers.  You'll have to look at the plugin and see it's support for new elements...if they aren't added or recognized by the plugin, they'll have no "tree-ish" behavior.